# Does the electric field of a battery exist before a wire is connected outside?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, metal

Imagine a galavanic cell.

What I am wondering is, what causes the inital oxidation of the less nobel metal to occur *initally*. Is the electric field there before you connect a wire, which would allow electrons to move through the outside wire?
If not, what does the wire change on the physical level?

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, there is an electric field around a disconnected cell -- an *electrostatic* field, just as if you ran a comb through your hair and p;laced it near an electroscope.

   In fact, one of the longest-running experiment is the [Clarendon Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_Electric_Bell) at Oxford University, running since 1840, relying on that field.
2. Electricity can flow even if there is no direct current path, through *capacitance*. When a charged object is placed near another object, electrostatic force induces a charge in the other object.

   Think of it as a **verrrrry** low frequency electromagnetic wave. If one takes ten seconds to move the objects, the *fundamental* frequency is 0.1 Hz. Note that such rdiation can extend to X-rays and gamma rays, as when a fast-moving electron is stopped *abruptly*: [bremsstrahlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung).

Answer (score 0):

What I write here may be opinion based, please be patient.

Inside the bulk metal, Ohm's law always applies, involving disconnected cell.
Ohm's law is expressed as $\mathbf{J}=\sigma\mathbf{E}$, where $\mathbf{J}$ is the electric current density, $\sigma$ is the electric conductivity and $\mathbf{E}$ is the electric field.
Inside the bulk metal of the disconnected cell, no electric current density is experimentally observed; this means $\mathbf{J}=0$.
Since $\sigma$ is positive, the total electric field must be zero ($\mathbf{E}=0$) in this disconnected cell case.
When the circuit is connected and closed, we observe non-zero electric current denisty, which means that the electric field is non-zero for such a closed circuit.

This discussion does not mean that the electric field caused by the electric scalar potential ($\mathbf{E}=-\nabla\phi$)
is zero in the case of an open circuit. One source of the electric field is the scalar potential $\phi$ and another source of the electric field comes from the time variation of the vector potential $\mathbf{A}$. That is, in the mathematical expression $\mathbf{E}=-\nabla\phi-\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{A}$.

Unfortunately, the role of the electric field coming from the vector potential is not clarified even in 2024.